# You do not have permission to view this directory or page ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know there is a lot of topic here talks about this problem , but before i posted i tried all the solution and nothing works with me !

Anyway my problem is when i try to open my admin panel path :

```
xoxo.com/admin
```

i got this error :

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

But when i request this path :

```
xoxo.com/admin/create
```

it's working 100%

with known i did not made any change on the files or server .

anyway here is the controller content of admin page:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private SmartBookLibraryModel db = new SmartBookLibraryModel();

    // GET: Admin/Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new admin_DashBoard();
        vm.Book = db.Books.ToList();
        vm.Category = db.Categories.ToList();
        vm.Group = db.Groups.ToList();
        vm.AspNetUser = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Also the Actual path for the page as the follow :

```
Admin/Admin/Index
```

But i used routing :

```
 public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {

        context.MapRoute(
             "Admin",
             "Admin",
             new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
            );


        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

}
```

thanks and wish someone help me with that !

Comment: Can you post your config file <authorization>  settings

Comment: @DaniDev I don't have <authorization> in web.config file